# Pivot dataframe replace transpose with pivot

Tags: python, pandas

I have below dataframe and want to transpose the data for this dataframe. I am using transpose however transpose is slow when the dataframe has more data. How to tanspose by using pivot.

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({
                    'A':[45, 88, 56],
                   'B':[10, 20, 30],
                   'C':[5, 10, 15]})
index_ = [ 'max','min','avg']
df_test.index = index_
df_test.T
```

Dataf frame  is as below

[image]

Expected output :

[image]

Comment: What makes you believe that you can use a `pivot` and that this would be faster? Is your data type homogeneous?

Comment: I want to try pivot and see if it will be faster

Comment: Well, `pivot` is not going to transpose the data this way. This is a different operation.

Comment: what will be the other option then to replace Transpose

Comment: Probably none. Don't you believe that if there was a faster way, `transpose` would already do this? You didn't answer the question about the data type. Please provide the output of `df.dtypes` and `df.T.dtypes` if you have some objects, this will make everything slower.

Comment: you can test if numpy transpose function performs faster, - but you will have more steps.
`df_arr = df_test.to_numpy().transpose()
df = pd.DataFrame(df_arr, columns= df_test.index)
df.index = list(df_test.columns)`